# After registering to my website instead of inserting the data to the sql server, an error message appears

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

In my asp website i have a register form that sends data to the database.
When a user enters his data, after submitting, an error is appeared that says:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

This is the code:
signup.aspx.cs-

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = Request.Form["name"];
    string email = Request.Form["email"];
    string password = Request.Form["password"];
    string fileName = "Database.mdf";
    string sql = "INSERT INTO UserInfo VALUES('" + name + "','" + email + "','" + password + "')";
    MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(fileName,sql);
}
```

MyAdoHelper.DoQuery-

```
public static void DoQuery(string fileName, string sql)
{

    SqlConnection conn = ConnectToDb(fileName);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    com.Dispose();
    conn.Close();

}
```

MyAdoHelper.ConnectToDb-

```
 public static SqlConnection ConnectToDb(string fileName)
{
    string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/");
    path += fileName;
    //string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/" + fileName);
    string connString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" +
                         path +
                         ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    return conn;

}
```

My database name is Database.mdf and its under App_Data Folder

Could anyone tell me what is the problem?
Thx !

Comment: Not related to the error, do you know about SQL injection attacks? If you build your SQL queries that way (string concatenation, and without validation), your site will be vulnerable. And you're storing passwords as cleartext.

Comment: just set debug point at " string connString " in your MyAdoHelper.ConnectToDb,check connection string. compare your connection string at https://www.connectionstrings.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

Above error message clearly suggest that the instance name ".\SQLEXPRESS" is wrong. Please first confirm the instance name.

By the word "registering" I guess you means "Hosted in a webserver". IN that case the connection string most probably won't work that way. We can find the connection string for the SQL server in you hosting providers control panel. Or you can ask them for connection string and mention them that you are using a SQL DB Local file which will be attached with the application. As an example you can provide them your current connection string.